# source an R script file inside an Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose that I have two folders called F1 and F2 inside folder F. My Rmd file is inside F1 and I have R script files inside F2. Let's say there is an R script called R_1 inside folder F2 which includes basically a function called fn_1 inside and this function accepts two inputs. I want to run this function fn_1 inside a code chunk in my Rmd file for different inputs and get their outputs, can I do such a thing? Thank you!

```
source('../F2/R_1.R')
x <- 1:10
w <- 1:10
fn_1(x,w)
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this. What problem are you seeing when you are trying it?

Comment: it says that object fn_1 is not found @KonradRudolph

Comment: Then you’ll need to post a [mcve].

Comment: the question is completely clear, so I do not think it is needed! @KonradRudolph

Comment: It’s definitely needed. Please refer to the *very first sentence* of the link I posted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph pointed out that it should work like this, which means the MWE should work as well. If so, then why is this actually a question at all?